# How to remove some of the headers of an HTTP request?

Tags: iphone, httprequest

I need to remove some of the headers, e.g. `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, etc. from an HTTP request being sent from iPhone to server.

`NSMutableURLRequest` and `CFHTTPMessageRef` don't have a way to override what is being sent in the header. It seems like there is no easy way to approach that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm interested why you want to do this. There might be other ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using -setAllHTTPHeaderFields? The docs say it replaces all current fields (rather than appending).

Comment: From my testing, any headers passed in to setAllHTTPHeaderFields will replace, not be appended to, existing headers.